# Array disappears after assigning

Tags: javascript

I'm using the below code to assign an array to a key of my object.

I can't figure out why user_dict shows 'labels' is an empty array instead of containing some_array.

```
  let user_dict = {}
  let some_array = ['test', false]
    console.log('user_dict is ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user_dict)))
    if (!user_dict['labels']) {
        user_dict['labels'] = []
    }
    if (!user_dict['labels']['test1']) {
        user_dict['labels']['test1'] = some_array
    }
    console.log('user_dict2 is ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user_dict)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your mistake is just `user_dict['labels'] = []`  it's an array, array works with index (integer). user_dict['labels']['test1'] is a hash, so just replace [] by {} in initialisation...

It's works now ;)

```
let user_dict = {}
let some_array = ['test', false]
    console.log('user_dict is ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user_dict)))
    if (!user_dict['labels']) {
        user_dict['labels'] = {} //<====== correction is here
    }
    if (!user_dict['labels']['test1']) {
        user_dict['labels']['test1'] = some_array
    }
    console.log('user_dict2 is ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user_dict)))
```

Comment: "_user_dict['labels']['test1'] is a hash_" What do you mean by hash here?

Comment: Hash is define by `{}`, it can contain string key instead of Array are only integer from 0.
Note: in JS Hash and Object are confused (because you can add method and prototype to a Hash, so it became an Object, but in fact is always an Object : `typeof {test:42}
"object"`

Comment: Do you mean an object? I don't think hashes have anything to do with it.

Comment: i edit my comment sry, its the same in JS ;)

Comment: I'm afraid you're misusing the term hash here. An object in JavaScript might be stored in a HashMap underwater by the engine that is being used, but from a JS point of view, it has nothing to do with it. (Also, a hash is used by hashmaps, but generally a hash itself is a value smaller value that is derived a larger value using a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).)

Comment: I'm Ruby user, so Hash is Hash and Array... an Array, and Object was another thing... :)
https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html

Hash deal with dynamic keys with associed value (dosn't matter how its implemente by langage), and Array is same but with autoincremented integer from 0 (no choice in key)

In "normal" langage, Object can invoke method by `obj.foo` and Hash by `h['foo']` (Array `a[42]`).
JS is just special because merge this two concepts in one : we can call `obj['foo']` or `obj.foo` is the same... so "Hash" was included in Object ;)